# QtCreator + MSVC 2015: ошибка компиляции

Tags: visual-c++, qt5, qtcreator

Есть некая библиотека, которую необходимо использовать в Qt-проекте. При попытке ее подключения возникает ошибка компиляции:

```
error C2371: 'int32_t': redefinition; different basic types
 D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdint.h(19): note: see declaration of 'int32_t'
```

Ругается вот на это определение в хидере:

```
#ifndef __int32_t_defined
#define __int32_t_defined
/**
* \brief 32 bit signed integer
*/
#ifdef _WIN32
Ошибка здесь ---> typedef long int32_t;
#else
typedef int int32_t;
#endif
#endif
/*@}*/
```

В файле stdint.h находим следующее:

```
typedef int   int32_t;
```

Если компилировать тестовый пример без использования Qt, то такой ошибки не возникает. Видимо, дело в каких-то ключах, вопрос в каких?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить заголовочный файл stdint.h как можно выше до включения заголовочных файлов Qt. После включения добавить:

```
#define __int32_t_defined
```

В этом случае сработает защита от повторного включения и `int32_t` не будет определен дважды.

Comment: Не помогло, та же ошибка

Comment: Немного поправил ответ.

Comment: Спaсибо! Заработало. Понять бы причину... При чем тут Qt?

Comment: Заработало, да не так, увы... Мне нужно, чтобы работали дефайны из библиотечного хидера, то есть, typedef long int32_t, а не typedef int int32_t как в случае предложенного Вами решения...

Comment: Вы можете тогда наоборот поступить - перед подключением библиотеки добавить `#undef int32_t`.